# Get edit order id magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, edit-order, admin-order-create

I have to get order id in admin edit order?

I have tried to get order id from quote but the order creating new so that I don't fetch order id. Is there any way to get order id in admin edit order?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Backend\Model\Session');
$quoteData = $quote->getQuote()->getData();
```

But I can't fetch any order detail.

Comment: can you add more description and also what you tried so far. it will be very helpful.

Comment: can you please check it @QaisarSatti

Comment: can you share your edit order url?

Comment: domain.com/admin/sales/order_create/index/key/aa701fe990ca5037ae2250eb8d57843dbb9d4be3ad71898c4442f95b5bf1bf12/

Comment: this is new order create page not order edit can you share what you want to do here with order. For getting the order id you need event for that

Comment: @QaisarSatti the order edit page cancel last order and create new order so that action is order create? You can check sales_order_edit_index.xml file in Magento_Sales/adminhtml/layout file

Comment: have you checked what written on that file `<update handle="sales_order_create_index"/>` so kindly share your problem what you want do here with order. You will get order id after the order is placed.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I have checked sales_order_create_index.xml file and I want only order id which is display in header only.

Comment: Added the answer kindly check and feedback me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento using the quote session for that following code is magento is using to get order increment id.

```
protected $_sessionQuote; 
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,

    ) {


        $this->_sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
    }


$this->_sessionQuote->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

So here is an update code for you make things clear.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote');
echo  $quote->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: Absolutely right answer Thanks for helping me out. you saved my time. +1 vote

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't solve my problem, In case If you're using plugin for class

> Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction

than you can get order id in params

```
$controller->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

In any plugin you can get it by

```
$this->request->getParams();
```

Hope it helps.